# function prop as dependency for useCallback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am not really sure when we should avoid using useCallback, if there is any harm (memory reallocation). For example lets say I have a component with two props, {onSave, onClose} and one state viewName. is bellow handler function will be optimized with these dependencies?

```
  const handleSaveView = useCallback(() => {
    onSaveView(viewName, selectedViewList);
    onClose();
  }, [onSaveView, onClose, viewName]);
```

Comment: The question you've asked requires knowing more about your app than what you've shown. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

`useCallback` saves a function you pass to it and, in the future, returns that function instead of the new one if any of the values in the dependency array change.

This comes at a cost, mostly in the tests of the dependency array and, most of the time, it isn't worth using. It's a very tempting tool for [premature optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization).

There are times when that cost is worth paying, such as when the function has an internal state or it is a dependency of another hook (so recreating the function would trigger the other hook to re-run).

[Dmitri Pavlutin's "Your Guide to React.useCallback()"](https://dmitripavlutin.com/dont-overuse-react-usecallback/) covers this in more depth.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes, but make sure you also memoize (e.g., via `useCallback`) your onSave and onClose handlers where you create them, if you create them in render cycle (as you do with `handleSaveView`). Don’t forget to pass `selectedViewList` as dependency, too.

#### Why use React memoization hooks

There are two reasons to React memoization hooks (of which `useCallback` is one) for: A) reference equality, and B) computation caching. Your example is about reference equality, so we’ll talk only about that.

#### Why memoize for reference equality

To avoid extra re-renders (i.e., rendering a component again even if nothing changed).

React will want to render whenever a prop changes, and strict equality operator is used when checking whether a prop changed. With JavaScript’s strict equality operator, *a non-primitive value is different every time you instantiate it,* even if you instantiate it the exact same way.

This includes traditional objects, functions, arrays:

```js
{ foo: 'bar' } !== { foo: 'bar' }
function a() { return true } !== function a() { return true }
[1, 2, 3] !== [1, 2, 3]
```

Therefore, if you 1) create a non-primitive value `{ foo: 'bar' }`  within render cycle (i.e., in the body of a React function component) and 2) pass this value as prop to another component, then you need a way of telling React that `{ foo: 'bar' }` is the same as `{ foo: 'bar' }` if you want to avoid unnecessary renders of that component.

#### How hooks ensure reference equality

React’s hooks allow you to declare that “this non-primitive value is the same if all of those other values (dependencies) are the same”. But again, React uses strict equality to check whether dependencies are the same.

#### Memoizing is useless if you don’t ensure reference equality of dependencies

Everything is fine if your dependencies are *primitive values* (numbers, strings, `null`, and so on).

However, in case of this question, I assume `onSave` and `onClose` are functions. Non-primitive values. Which means, if you declare them in some component’s render cycle, they are re-created every render. Therefore, **unless you also memoize them, your memoization will be completely pointless**, your `handleSaveView` will be new every time, and if you pass it to another component it may be re-rendered even if you don’t expect it.